# Selective merge of array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays containing hashes:

```
a = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS"},
  {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"},
]

b = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"},
  {:umc=>"10EE", :code=>"99"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :code=>"44"},
  {:umc=>"1973", :code=>"55"},
]
```

and would like to selectively merge them into another array with hashes as follows:

```
c = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS", :code=>"23"},
  {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :code=>"55"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"} :code=>"44"},
]
```

I am using the code

```
combo=(a+b).group_by{|h| h[:umc]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

which merges the two arrays just fine, but I would like the result to only include items that appear in the first array.

As a second idea, it would be great to be able to have two results, one that consists of items combined from both initial arrays and a second containing elements that are in the first but not in the second.

Comment: How about `:umc=>"10EE"` ?

Comment: Sorry 10EE was not supposed to appear in the first array. Needless to say the actual data has over 10,000 items. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b.reduce(a) do |memo, e| 
  (ae = memo.detect { |ae| ae[:umc] == e[:umc] }) && ae.merge!(e)
  memo
end
```

Cary proposed “more readable” way to express merging, plus whether we don’t want to mutate initial `a` array, we should `dup` it’s elements:

```
b.reduce(a.map(&:dup)) do |memo, e| 
  ae = memo.detect { |ae| ae[:umc] == e[:umc] }
  ae.merge!(e) if ae
  memo
end
```

Comment: Good solution, but it should be noted that it mutates the elements of `a`.  Imo, it would read better if the first line were split into two, the latter being `ae.merge!(e) if ae`.

Comment: You might also change `b.reduce(a)` to `(a+b).reduce({})` in case two hashes in `a` have the same value for `:umc`. (That's a mistake I made that was flagged out by the OP.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I added `.dup` to avoid mutation of initial `a` array, thanks. Regarding your second comment, I did not get a point. The result will not cut `a` by any mean, it will just merge it against `b`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - The first proposed code actually does everything I want or at least I think it does. My plan is to take a look at all the other solutions until I understand why some of them only include results where :umc has a match in both arrays. This solution does the merge as it should and keeps a while adding the elements from b based on the match.  Thank you both for the solution and the education.

Comment: @berlin You are welcome. Please be aware of a difference between reducing `a` (as it was before Cary pointed out that way we mutate the initial a array because of inplace `merge!`) and `a.dup`, that does not mutate any initial input. The latter seems to be more reliable.

Comment: I don't believe that `dup` helps because it is the elements of `a` themselves that are being mutated.

Answer (score 0):

Not be very elegant, but it should be quite efficient computation wise, as it is O(n+m) on average. I doubt you can get it faster than this. On the downside it burns a lot of space.

```
def selective_merge(a, b)
  merged = {}
  a.each {|v| merged[v[:umc]] = [v[:umc], v[:title]]}
  b.each {|v| merged[v[:umc]] = merged[v[:umc]] << v[:code] if merged[v[:umc]]}
  merged.map {|k,v| {:umc => v[0], :title => v[1], :code => v[2]}}
end
```

Comment: You could also make it more generic by passing in the select operation and make it work with more keys in the hashes.

Comment: This is a great answer but I'm still new at both Ruby and SO. The two initial arrays might have an arbitrary number of elements and so I'd like to adjust the code to merge ALL of the elements of both hashes if the element :umc matches, without having to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your code as follows:

```
bb = b.select { |f| a.any? { |h| h[:umc] == f[:umc] } }
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :code=>"44"},
  #    {:umc=>"1973", :code=>"55"}] 
(a + bb).group_by { |g| g[:umc] }.map { |_,v| v.reduce(:merge) }
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS", :code=>"23"},
  #    {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :code=>"55"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR", :code=>"44"}]
```

but it would be more efficient to calculate `bb` thusly:

```
require 'set'
umc_a_vals = a.map { |g| g[:umc] }.to_set
  #=> #<Set: {"11VE", "1973", "1140"}>
bb = b.select { |f| umc_a_vals.include(f[:umc]) }
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :code=>"44"},
  #    {:umc=>"1973", :code=>"55"}]
```

Here's another way:

```
f = a.group_by { |g| g }.map { |_,v| v.reduce(:merge) }
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS"},
  #    {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"}] 
b.each_with_object(f) do |g,h| 
  (h.update(g[:umc]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }) if h.key?(g[:umc])
end.values
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS", :code=>"23"},
  #    {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :code=>"55"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR", :code=>"44"}]
```

The calculation of `f` is so similar to your code that I don't think an explanation is needed.

We now merge the hash:

```
{ g[:umc]=g }
  #=> { "11VE"=>{:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"} }
```

into `h` if `h` has a key `"11VE"`, which it does. For that we use the form of [Hash#update](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that employs the block:

```
{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
```

to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

The block variables equal:

```
_ #=> "11VE"
o #=> {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS"}
n #=> {:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"}
```

so the result of the block calculation is:

```
o.merge(n)
  #=> {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBAR, :code=>"23"}
```

which is the updated value of `h[:umc]`.

Aside: I used the local variable `_` for the value of the key to draw attention to the fact that it is not being used in the block calculation. The variables `o` and `n` are commonly used to represent the "old" and "new" values, respectively.

The merging into `h` of the hashes constructed from the remaining values of `b` is done similarly.

The final step is to extract the values of `h`.

As a second example, suppose:

```
a = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS"},
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :author=>"Billy-Bob"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"}
]
```

We obtain:

```
f = a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:umc]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) } }  
  #=> {"11VE"=>{:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :author=>"Billy-Bob"},
  #    "1140"=>{:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"}} 
b.each_with_object(f) do |g,h| 
  (h.update(g[:umc]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }) if h.key?(g[:umc])
end.values
  #=> [{:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :author=>"Billy-Bob", :code=>"23"},
  #    {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR", :code=>"44"}]
```

Comment: Your second example is running great but it seems to discard any element in a which doesn't have a corresponding match in b. I need to keep ALL elements of a regardless of the matching with b. I just don't want any b that don't appear in a.    I'm slowly working through each of the proposed solutions mostly to get myself up to speed on using ruby (version 2.0)

Comment: Good catch. (Readers: the problem with the second method I offered was if that `g` and `h` are elements of `a` and `g[:umc]=h[:umc]`, the first hash would be overwritten by the second). I've fixed it and given another example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# @a - Pivot array(elements that will be in result array)
# @b - Array which contains intersecting elements
# @group - attribute name, which identify similarity of elements
def c_join(a, b, group)
  result = []
  a.each do |a_i|
    similar = b.detect{ |b_i| b_i[group] == a_i[group] }
    result << a_i.merge(similar)
  end
  result
end
```

Testing

```
a = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS"},
  {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR"},
]

b = [
  {:umc=>"11VE", :code=>"23"},
  {:umc=>"10EE", :code=>"99"},
  {:umc=>"1140", :code=>"44"},
  {:umc=>"1973", :code=>"55"},
]

c_join(a, b, :umc)
```

result

```
[
  {:umc=>"11VE", :title=>"FOOBARS", :code=>"23"}, 
  {:umc=>"1973", :title=>"ZOOBARS", :code=>"55"}, 
  {:umc=>"1140", :title=>"TINYBAR", :code=>"44"}
]
```